# nltk installation on my work computer

Tags: permissions, installation, nltk

I am trying to install nltk on my work computer.  I have admin access, but I keep getting the following error. Clearly I am doing something wrong or there is a permission issue I need to resolve, but I am not sure what. I would be grateful for any tips/advice.

[error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wNck.png)

Comment: are you installing this via `pip` or what?

Answer (score 0):

1. you can download the nltk library files from this link -https://pypi.org/project/nltk/#files and unzip them.
2. Open CMD and navigate to that folder.
3. Execute "python setup.py install" command to install the nltk library.